# Signed in via Huawei ID played 40 min game in trial mode, switched to another Huawei ID, remaining trial period was displaying 60. Is this problem?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I have captured all logs and searched for the keyword HwJos. The logs related to the problem were as follows:

1.Logs generated after the player had played for 40 minutes shows that the remaining period is 20 minutes.

2.Logs generated after the player switched to another HUAWEI ID shows the remaining period is 60 minutes.

[image]

Comment: Clearly the time is tied to the ID, not the device. This seems reasonable. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal phenomenon.

If a player signs in to a game using a HUAWEI ID that has not been used on a device before, the device ID cannot be obtained because the HUAWEI ID has not been authorized for sign-in. As a result, the remaining trial period cannot be obtained. In this case, Huawei will consider that the remaining trial duration is 60 minutes by default.

After the HUAWEI ID is authorized to sign in to the game, Huawei can obtain the device ID and the player can play a trial. The Huawei SDK client queries the remaining trial period every 5 minutes after the trial starts, and the game trial period is obtained based on the device information. If the trial period is 20 minutes (1 hour in total), the identity verification pop-up will be displayed.